# unable to start Pivotal tc server in Spring Tools Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

i'm using Spring tools suite to develop a web app, but when i want to run the app, i encounter a problem with the server "Pivotal tc server" and this is the error

```
java.lang.Error: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:644)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494) 
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:621)
... 7 more 
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
... 8 more 
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8082]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:556)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
... 10 more 
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```